# Can't reactivate Mathematica after reinstalling my system from scratch

Tags: installation, licensing

Earlier today I screwed up something, and was forced to reinstall my system (Arch Linux) from scratch. Everything went smoothly, except for one thing: I can't reactivate my Mathematica license. I was told that I need to perform a “system transfer”, so I submitted a “system transfer” request, and now:

- My activation key was sent to Customer Support for “review”. But Wolfram didn't tell me how long my key will remain pending “review”.
- My license, which was supposed to last until March 2018, only lasts until this April 6th. This is outrageous!

What do I do?

Comment: Write to Wolfram.

Comment: Interesting. Write them and let us know what the result is and how long it takes. I am planning a reinstall as well so I better be prepared (although in my case of dual boot windows + linux, they force me to have 2 licenses).

Comment: Hi; Used to happen to me way back in the days of XP before I went to linux. Every time I had to restore or put those restore CD's in I had to call Wolfram up and get a new license. Used to happen on the average of every 21 days. But they always gave me a new one right then and there over the phone. What is this review jazz? What are you supposed to do in the meantime? Call em up and do not stop calling until you reach a human being.